# data is not showing properly in slickgrid: some columns are not showing the data at startup

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, dataview

Im working with slickgrid to show my data on UI. I'm using dataview to set the data in the grid. The problem I'm getting is when I set the data in the data view , at start it just shows only first 3-4 columns filled with data and all other columns empty. While when I navigate to last page (rihgt now I have 3 pages in slickgrid pagination) it shows complete data, then it works fine for all the page (i.e. after going to last page , it shows data for all pages for all columns). I tried rendering grid and refreshing the dataview but its not working. 
here is my code for rendering the slickgrid on page.

```
var data = [];
var column = [ {
    id : 'fillid',
    name : 'Fill ID',
    field : 'fillid'
}, {
    id : 'oid',
    name : 'Order ID',
    field : 'oid'
}, {
    id : 'price',
    name : 'Price',
    field : 'price'
}, {
    id : 'fillQTY',
    name : 'Fill QTY',
    field : 'fillQTY'
}, {
    id : 'symbol',
    name : 'symbol',
    field : 'symbol'
}, {
    id : 'cumQTY',
    name : 'cumQTY',
    field : 'cumQTY'
}, {
    id : 'fillPX',
    name : 'Fill PX.',
    field : 'fillPX'
}, {
    id : 'transactiontime',
    name : 'Transaction Time',
    field : 'transactiontime'
}, {
    id : 'ccy',
    name : 'Currency',
    field : 'ccy'
}, {
    id : 'venue',
    name : 'Venue',
    field : 'venue'
}, {
    id : 'fixingdate',
    name : 'Fixing Date',
    field : 'fixingdate'
}, {
    id : 'sendtime',
    name : 'Send Time',
    field : 'sendtime',
    width : 110
}, {
    id : 'side',
    name : 'Side',
    field : 'side'
}, {
    id : 'orderQTY',
    name : 'Order QTY',
    field : 'orderQTY'
} ];
var resData;

resData = fillsDATA.data;
for (j = 0; j < resData.length; j++) {
    var obj = {
        id : j ,
        fillid : resData[j].fillid,
        oid : resData[j].oid,
        price : resData[j].price,
        fillQTY : resData[j].fillQTY,
        symbol : resData[j].symbol,
        cumQTY : resData[j].cumQTY,
        fillPX : resData[j].fillPX,
        transactiontime : resData[j].transactiontime,
        ccy : resData[j].ccy,
        venue : resData[j].venue,
        fixingdate : resData[j].fixingdate,
        sendtime : resData[j].sendtime,
        side : resData[j].side,
        orderQTY : resData[j].orderQTY
    };
    data[data.length] = obj;
}
var options = {
    editable : true,
    enableAddRow : false,
    autoEdit : false,
    autoHeight : true
};
var groupItemMetadataProvider = new Slick.Data.GroupItemMetadataProvider();
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({
    groupItemMetadataProvider : groupItemMetadataProvider,
    inlineFilters : true
});
var tradesGrid = new Slick.Grid(FillsGrid, dataView, column, options);
tradesGrid.registerPlugin(groupItemMetadataProvider);
var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, tradesGrid,
        $("#tradesPager"));
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    tradesGrid.updateRowCount();
    tradesGrid.render();
});
dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    tradesGrid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    tradesGrid.render();
});

dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();
dataView.setPagingOptions({
    pageSize : 20
});
tradesGrid.render();
tradesGrid.updateRowCount();
dataView.refresh();
```

I'm using the grid in many other different place in my app and its working fine I don't understand where I'm going wrong here.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this the exact code used elsewhere that works correctly? Or is there something different about the code you are using here (e.g. columns, pagination, etc.)

Comment: just names of columns/data values are different but the implamentation is the same. When i re-order columns, it suddenly shows the whole data (may be it used some rerender type function internally on reordering which fixes it) but don't know why its not showing data at startup.

Comment: Try this: At the end of the file, move the `dataView.refresh()` above the `tradesGrid.render()`

Comment: @Edward I tried but same result.